# How to prevent first frame from disposing while second frame is open?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to prevent closing the first frame while the second is still open frame is open in a Java GUI? Both the frames are related to each other.

Comment: how to prevent closing the first frame while the second frame is still open in java GUI. both the frames are related to each-other.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to privide a [mre]. Without any code, you are not likely to get the help you want. Nonetheless, this should be considered: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) Closing the "first frame" will most likely terminate your program, therefore also closing the "second frame".

Comment: Give this a read: [Preventing JFrame window from closing](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/preventing-jframe-window-from-closing). Play with it a bit.

Comment: Don't use muiltiple JFrames. An application should only have a single JFrame. If you need a second child window then use a `modal JDialog`. You will not be able to click on the JFrame until the dialog is closed.

Comment: @camickr Perhaps questioner would like a multi-frame program like Eclipse?  Or for multiple reasons given in this answer to another question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961122  Myself, I have made an application that allows users to float JInternalFrames to become JFrames and vice versa.